# How to run two codes asynchronously?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run two module that run the same code with different variable as the webpage doesn't allow me to run more then 40 data web scraping.

The way I fix this is by splitting the script e.g.:

First Module: `For IntRow = 43 To 83`
Second Module: `For IntRow = 84 To 124`

```vb
Sub pullDataFromWeb43to83()
    
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False
        
    ie.navigate "website.com"
        
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
        
    Set Doc = ie.Document
        
    For IntRow = 43 To 83
    
        ie.Document.getElementById("main-search-input").Value = Range("B" & IntRow).Value
        Doc.getElementById("btn-search").Click
        
        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
        
        Fundamental = Doc.getElementsByClassName("badge badge-pill p-1").Item(0).innerText
        Technical = Doc.getElementsByClassName("badge badge-pill p-1").Item(1).innerText
        strEPS = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(1).innerText
        strPE = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(3).innerText
        strPEG = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(5).innerText
        AltmanZ = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(7).innerText
        Beaver = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(9).innerText
        CurrentRatio = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(11).innerText
        DebtEquity = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(13).innerText
        FCFYield = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(15).innerText
        DividendPerShare = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(17).innerText
        RevenueQoQ = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(19).innerText
        RevenueYoY = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(21).innerText
        ProfitQoQ = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(23).innerText
        ProfitYoY = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(25).innerText
        NTAQoQ = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(27).innerText
        ProfitMargin = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(29).innerText
        ROE = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(31).innerText
        ROIC = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(33).innerText
        DividendYield = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(35).innerText
        
        Range("P" & IntRow).Value = Fundamental
        Range("Q" & IntRow).Value = Technical
        Range("R" & IntRow).Value = strEPS
        Range("S" & IntRow).Value = strPE
        Range("T" & IntRow).Value = strPEG
        Range("U" & IntRow).Value = AltmanZ
        Range("V" & IntRow).Value = Beaver
        Range("W" & IntRow).Value = CurrentRatio
        Range("X" & IntRow).Value = DebtEquity
        Range("Y" & IntRow).Value = FCFYield
        Range("Z" & IntRow).Value = DividendPerShare
        Range("AA" & IntRow).Value = RevenueQoQ
        Range("AB" & IntRow).Value = RevenueYoY
        Range("AC" & IntRow).Value = ProfitQoQ
        Range("AD" & IntRow).Value = ProfitYoY
        Range("AE" & IntRow).Value = NTAQoQ
        Range("AF" & IntRow).Value = ProfitMargin
        Range("AG" & IntRow).Value = ROE
        Range("AH" & IntRow).Value = ROIC
        Range("AI" & IntRow).Value = DividendYield
        
    Next
        
    ie.Quit
    MsgBox "done"
        
End Sub
    
' ______________________________
    
Sub pullDataFromWeb84to124()
    
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
       
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False
        
    ie.navigate "website.com"
        
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
        
    Set Doc = ie.Document
        
    For IntRow = 84 To 124
        
        ie.Document.getElementById("main-search-input").Value = Range("B" & IntRow).Value
        Doc.getElementById("btn-search").Click
        
        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
        
        Fundamental = Doc.getElementsByClassName("badge badge-pill p-1").Item(0).innerText
        Technical = Doc.getElementsByClassName("badge badge-pill p-1").Item(1).innerText
        strEPS = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(1).innerText
        strPE = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(3).innerText
        strPEG = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(5).innerText
        AltmanZ = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(7).innerText
        Beaver = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(9).innerText
        CurrentRatio = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(11).innerText
        DebtEquity = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(13).innerText
        FCFYield = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(15).innerText
        DividendPerShare = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(17).innerText
        RevenueQoQ = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(19).innerText
        RevenueYoY = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(21).innerText
        ProfitQoQ = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(23).innerText
        ProfitYoY = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(25).innerText
        NTAQoQ = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(27).innerText
        ProfitMargin = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(29).innerText
        ROE = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(31).innerText
        ROIC = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(33).innerText
        DividendYield = Doc.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(35).innerText
        
        Range("P" & IntRow).Value = Fundamental
        Range("Q" & IntRow).Value = Technical
        Range("R" & IntRow).Value = strEPS
        Range("S" & IntRow).Value = strPE
        Range("T" & IntRow).Value = strPEG
        Range("U" & IntRow).Value = AltmanZ
        Range("V" & IntRow).Value = Beaver
        Range("W" & IntRow).Value = CurrentRatio
        Range("X" & IntRow).Value = DebtEquity
        Range("Y" & IntRow).Value = FCFYield
        Range("Z" & IntRow).Value = DividendPerShare
        Range("AA" & IntRow).Value = RevenueQoQ
        Range("AB" & IntRow).Value = RevenueYoY
        Range("AC" & IntRow).Value = ProfitQoQ
        Range("AD" & IntRow).Value = ProfitYoY
        Range("AE" & IntRow).Value = NTAQoQ
        Range("AF" & IntRow).Value = ProfitMargin
        Range("AG" & IntRow).Value = ROE
        Range("AH" & IntRow).Value = ROIC
        Range("AI" & IntRow).Value = DividendYield
        
    Next
        
    ie.Quit
    MsgBox "84 To 124 UI JOOO ASHIAPP !!"
    
End Sub
```

I tried this to run these two modules asynchronously.

```vb
Sub Run_All_Script()
        
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
        
    Application.Run ("pullDataFromWeb6to42")
          
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    On Error GoTo 0
          
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Application.Run ("pullDataFromWeb43to83")
          
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    On Error GoTo 0
          
End Sub
    
Public Function getWebContents(ie As InternetExplorer, webAddress As String) As HTMLObjectElement
    '...
End Function
```

I end up with

1. error message
   [image]
2. debug error
   [image]

The code runs fine with button click for individual module.

Comment: VBA does not support multi-threading therefore you cannot run code asynchroniously in VBA. One code has to wait until the other finished (single-threading).

Comment: Beside what Pᴇʜ wrote about multi-threading. You wrote: `the webpage does't allow me to run more then 40 data web scrapping` And than: `First Module : For IntRow = 43 To 83` That's 41 scrappings ;-)